# Install4j duplicate shortcut on desktop

Tags: install4j

When installing an application (packed with install4j) onto a computer that already 
has it installed with admin and then with other user rights, 
the installer will produce another icon on the desktop 
resulting in 2 or more application icons.

To reproduce this:

1. Install the application as an admin user on windows
2. Log into another user account that is not an admin. 
   (A normal user account)
3. Install application once again, and after the client is finished installing it will produce another icon on the desktop

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different desktop folders involved, the public one and the user specific one. If the "Create for all users" property of the "Add a desktop link" action is selected, the action will try to create the link in the public folder, but that usually requires admin privileges. If you don't have admin privileges, you could check if such a file already exists in the public folder. The condition expression of the action could be set to something like:

```
if (!Util.hasFullAdminRights()) {
    File publicLink = new File(WinFileSystem.getSpecialFolder(
        SpecialFolder.DESKTOP, true), "launcher name.lnk");
    return !publicLink.exists();
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The fun stuff is when a normal user installs the app and AFTER THAT the admin decides to install the app. The user will also end up having 2 shortcuts as the "admin install" does not search each users' Desktops for shortcut presence - it will simply add it to public desktop folder thus making a new link on the screen...but this is another story.

Comment: That would be more difficult to prevent, since it's not really possible to enumerate users. You could heuristically process all subdirectories of C:\Users, but I'm not sure if I would really recommend that.